# Rails country_select for locale name - 'en-GB' not 'gb'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, rails-i18n

I'm currently using the country_select gem for users profiles. With the locales you can have `:en, :en-Us, :en-GB` and I see to change the current locale you can do `I18n.locale =`. So lets say I need to select 'United Kingdom' from the country_select, this will save `gb` into the database. Now I would like to change the locale to the users selected country but this will change it to `gb` which won't work as it needs to be 'en-GB' and this include the uppercase.

How would I go about doing this? This could also be the same for all the `es` locales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a helper method, which has a 'case' statement and returning the right result.

```
def prefix_locale(locale)
  case locale
    when 'gb'
      'en-GB'
    else
      locale
    end
end
```